# Deserialize body of result which is a byte array to json response

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to take the body of a result and deserialize it into JSON.

```
   val str = """ {"protectedBitcoinAddress":"moLM1zdPBSh81eykhfcoLZ3myqUSy9FRRG"} """
   val request : JsValue = Json.parse(str)
   println("Request: " + request.toString)
   val result : Future[Result] = createUnsignedNLockTime()(FakeRequest().withJsonBody(request))

   whenReady(result, timeout(19 seconds), interval(5 millis)) { res =>
    println("==============================")
    val e: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = res.body

    val bodyAsStr: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = e.run(play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee.fold("") { (memo, next) => memo + next })

    println("Body as string: " + Await.result(bodyAsStr,5 seconds))
    val bodyAsJsValue: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = e.map(play.api.libs.json.Json.parse)

    println("body as js: " + Await.result(bodyAsJsValue, 5 seconds))
    println("==============================")
  }
```

How do I take something of type `Enumerator[scala.Array[scala.Byte]]` and convert that to a Json object in the Playframework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
 [info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>import play.api.mvc.{Result, Results}
import play.api.mvc.{Result, Results}

scala>import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumerator, Iteratee}
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumerator, Iteratee}

scala>import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.json.Json

scala>import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

scala>import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala>import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala>val result: Result = Results.Ok(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(Map("k" -> "v")))).as("application/json")
result: play.api.mvc.Result = Result(200, Map(Content-Type -> application/json))

scala>val enumerator: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = result.body
enumerator: play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator$$anon$18@70d59654

scala>val bodyAsBytesEventually: Future[Array[Byte]] = enumerator.run(Iteratee.fold(Array.empty[Byte]) { (memo, nextChunk) => memo ++ nextChunk })
bodyAsBytesEventually: scala.concurrent.Future[Array[Byte]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@8786f46

scala>val bodyAsStrEventually = bodyAsBytesEventually.map(bytes => new String(bytes))
bodyAsStrEventually: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@442b7dd6

scala>val bodyAsStr = Await.result(bodyAsStrEventually, 1.seconds)
bodyAsStr: String = {"k":"v"} // In general, do not block unless you know what you are doing.
```

Comment: `bodyAsStr` does not work - here is what it prints for me: `Body as string: [B@5cc7c8f4`

Comment: `bodyAsJsValue` seems to represent a phantom value which is `f`

Comment: `bodyAsJsValue` is a `Future[JsValue]`.  Play is asynchronous.

Comment: Should have been more verbose - I'm using this piece of code to test the output `println("Body as string: " + Await.result(bodyAsStr,5 seconds))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Helpers.scala to convert your response of type byte array to string/json.

Ref: [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala) and [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html)

You can modify your code as:

```
    val str = """ {"protectedBitcoinAddress":"moLM1zdPBSh81eykhfcoLZ3myqUSy9FRRG"} """
    val request : JsValue = Json.parse(str)
    println("Request: " + request.toString)
    val result : Future[Result] = createUnsignedNLockTime()(FakeRequest().withJsonBody(request))

    whenReady(result, timeout(19 seconds), interval(5 millis)) { res =>


    println("==============================")
    val bodyAsStr = contentAsString(result)
    println("Body as string: " + bodyAsStr)

    val bodyAsJsValue = contentAsJson
    println("body as js: " + bodyAsJsValue)
    println("==============================")
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.